# can't use both getCurrentActivity() of activity and getSupportFragmentManager in the same method

Tags: android, android-fragments

So i was trying to use [tipsi-stripe](https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe) payments gateway which comes in a dialog box in the form of a BottomSheet. But everytime i extend class `AddCardDialogFragment` from BottomSheet instead of `DialogFragment` i get an error in the `cardDialog.show` method of `paymentRequestWithCardForm` in StripeModule as getCurrentActivity() and getSupportFragmentManager() are from different classes.

```
@ReactMethod
public void paymentRequestWithCardForm(ReadableMap params, final Promise promise) {
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
    try {
        ArgCheck.nonNull(currentActivity);
        ArgCheck.notEmptyString(mPublicKey);
        final AddCardDialogFragment cardDialog = AddCardDialogFragment.newInstance(
                mPublicKey,
                getErrorCode(mErrorCodes, "cancelled"),
                getDescription(mErrorCodes, "cancelled"),
                params.hasKey("createCardSource") && params.getBoolean("createCardSource")
        );
        cardDialog.setPromise(promise);
        cardDialog.show(currentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "AddNewCard");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        promise.reject(toErrorCode(e), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[Please check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpKOA.png)
Usually the error location contains currentActivity.getFragmentManager()

Please HELP

Comment: Where is the error? Can you show us a screen of the IDE or a Stacktrace?

Comment: i require both getCurrentActivity() and getSupportFragmentManager() in the same method. getFragmentManager() or extending AppCompatActivity will not work in my case.

Comment: Your current activity should be a fragment activity. Otherwise it doesn't work. And it doesn't even make sense to work

Comment: Cast your activity to FragmentActivity

Comment: not even getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager() or this.getSupportFragmentManager() is working in . this case. Please check the image.

Comment: FragmentActivity does not support getCurrentActivity() method.

Comment: You can either use one of 2. Either use Activity and fragmentManager or FragmentActivity and supportFragmentManager. Not both

Comment: Please check the circled section in the image where MainActivity@7478 value is being passed to the currentActivity object. FragmentManager passes the value of FragmentActivity@7074 in the  .show() method. Due to this the app crashes.